# How to fly a drone in Class D in Italy?

Tags: air-traffic-control, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, easa-regulations, class-d-airspace

I am traveling for a wedding which will take place in Monza Park, Italy. According to [Italian Airspace Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.minniti.italianairspacepro), the location I would like to fly, the southern half of the park, is technically in Class D airspace, which is restricted unless cleared by ATC.

[image]
Click image for full view.

I know that in the United States, the [FAA regulations state that](https://www.faa.gov/uas/getting_started/model_aircraft/) to fly in restricted airspace, you must:

> Notify the airport and air traffic control tower prior to flying within 5 miles of an airport*

Is flying within restricted airspace possible if I contact a local tower there? Who would I need to contact?

Comment: Btw, those requirements in the US are no longer in place; different ones are.

Comment: Don't confuse "controlled" airspace (such as class D) with "restricted" areas. They are two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class D airspace you are referring to is a control zone (CTR). According to article 24 of [Regulation for Remotely Piloted Aerial Vehicles](https://www.enac.gov.it/sites/default/files/allegati/2018-Lug/Regulation_RPAS_Issue_2_Rev_4_eng.pdf), the following applies to VLOS operations (emphasis mine):

> 4. Except as required by point 6 below, RPAS operations shall not be conducted:
>
> a) within ATZ and beneath take-off and landing paths or at a distance less than 5 km from the airport (ARP or published geographical coordinates) where ATZ is not established;
>
> b) **within CTR, without prejudice to point 5 below;**
>
> c) within active restricted areas and prohibited areas.
>
> 5. Operations within CTR are permitted only to RPA with operating take-off mass less than 25 kg, up to **maximum height of 70 m AGL** and within maximum horizontal distance of 200 m. **Beneath take  off  and  landing paths**, beyond ATZ boundaries and up to 15 km from  the airport, **maximum height shall be 30 m AGL**.
> 6. When  operations  do  not  meet  the  requirements set  forth  in  points  4a), 4b) and  5 above, operations shall be  carried  out  according  to  procedures  published  by  ENAC. When it  is required to operate within airspace as referred in point  4c) above,  operations  shall  be subject to specific authorization according to procedures published by ENAC.

Although you are pretty much directly below the approach path to Linate's runway 18, since the park is just over 15 km from the airport, you should be OK to fly up to 70 metres above ground as long as the drone stays within 200 metres of you.

Of course, there are also other applicable rules to consider: for example, you must wear a high vis vest with "Pilota di RPA" printed on it, you are not allowed to overfly crowds (including wedding guests) and the drone must be registered and identifiable.

Comment: I know this is an old question and OP has probably long left Italy again. Still think it deserves a proper answer, though.

Comment: With the Monza race tomorrow, and the question's applicability to other areas in Italy, I'm sure *many* will benefit from your answer, not just OP.

Answer (score 0):

According to my Foreflight, it is ground to 2,000 feet.  Also, in is attached to LIML airport Linate-Milan.  Look up the tower/Approach telephone number when you arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Italian aviation authorities to make sure (probably their ministry of transportation).

They'll be able to tell you what permits and licenses you need (if it's possible at all).